# Change .libPaths() in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm currently mounted to a remote server, which is where the .Rmd file lives.

I set my WD to this server, in addition to specifying a package library on this server.

However, the .libPaths() command doesn't seem to "stick", which means I cannot use the packages I'm calling below.

R markdown code:

```
require("knitr")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE)
.libPaths("/home/patrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir="/home/rebecca/missionbio/")

getwd()
.libPaths()

library(mixtools)
library(tapestri)
library(dplyr)
library(uwot)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(ggrepel)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(data.table)
```

Outputs:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
> 
> # Load required libraries. Install using install_packages("package_name") if necessary
> library(tapestri)
Error in library(tapestri) : there is no package called ‘tapestri’
```

How can I set the .libPaths for chunks in Rmarkdown?

Comment: Calling `.libPaths()` doesn't change anything ... do you mean something like `.libPaths(unique)c(getwd(), .libPaths())))`?

Comment: I called .libPaths() to show that it did not match what I set it to above: .libPaths("/home/patrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")

Comment: Does that directory (`"/home/patrick/..."`) exist? If it doesn't, `.libPaths` doesn't error or warn, it just ignores it. Try: `dir.exists("/home/patrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")`, confirm that it is `TRUE`. (Just a stab in the dark, sorry.)

Comment: Yep `dir.exists("/home/patrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")
[1] TRUE`. Can I ask -- in general, does Rmarkdown default to the library for the directory that Rstudio is in (I'm using R studio locally, but in the terminal, R on the remote machine)? Is there a different way to change .libPaths() in markdown files versus R documents generally?

Comment: Sorry, amendment -- in the R markdown file, the directory does not seem to exist, even though I set the WD to that remote server: `dir.exists("/home/patrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")
[1] FALSE`

Comment: So ... okay, I'm confused :-) You mention "remote" as if you test (successfully) on `local` and push to `remote` and get errors. Is that right?

Comment: I'm slightly concerned that one path looks like a Mac path and one looks like a linux path, and one seems to be using R 3.6 and one using R 4.0. You can't really share packages between major R versions. Also it doesn't seem that your output directly matches your input. If you've made edits, it's made this issue a bit more confusing.

Comment: @MrFlick I see -- maybe that's the issue. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is use R studio on my local machine as GUI/host for R markdown, while the .Rmd file, library, and data live on a remote server. I realized my path wasn't quite right, but once I got dir.exists(remote.lib.path) to be true in the markdown chunk, the chunk gets stuck trying to load said library. This is all to say that maybe this configuration is not possible.

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Maybe what I described in the comment above clarifies the situation? I may also be confusing myself (and others) because of the mismatch between the markdown file's directory (remote), the directory set within the markdown document, and the Rstudio console which is, of course, on my local machine.

Comment: If everything resides on a remote server but you access it via a network-share, then it is "local" as far as R is concerned. Anything else, and ... there is a lot to be explained to be able to help you.